# How to import react component in NextJS custom server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

**What:** I am trying to import a react component as a variable in Node.js

**Why:** I am going to use that react component to be rendered as static HTML, so that I can use it as the content in an email (using nodemailer).

I made a simple email template for a message (MessageTemplate.js):

```
const MessageTemplate = () => {
  return <div>MessageTemplate</div>;
};

export default MessageTemplate;
```

then, I import it into a controller folder:

```
const React = require("react");
const ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");

// This causes the error
const MessageTemplate =
  require("../components/emails/MessageTemplate.js").default;
```

I get this error:[image: error]

I'm trying to achieve what this [article](https://building.lang.ai/how-to-build-emails-with-react-fcf941b125d1) is doing, but for some reason, I can't seem to find a solution to this error.

Comment: Did you install babel?

Comment: Yes, I installed babel and set my presets as `["@babel/preset-react"]`

Comment: They never load react files as modules. They load the files as string and parse it using react dom. See https://github.com/lang-ai/react-emails/blob/master/server/createEmail.js#L34

Comment: You can't import files with JSX in them directly in node. You need to first compile the JSX files into vanilla Javascript node can understand, then import the compiled JS file rather than the source file with JSX in it. The linked article is very poorly written, it leaves out the need to call `npm build` to build those JS files into the `lib/` folder.

Comment: @Konrad, so you're saying they essentially use fs to find that template, convert it to a string, then use react dom server? If so, what is the `const Email = require('../lib/Email').default;` for?

Comment: Using React for a simple email template on the server seems... well, I imagine you have your reasons for doing this but it does seem like over-engineering a very simple task. Is there something wrong with just using HTML to create the template?

Comment: `../lib/Email` doesn't exist in the repo so I guess that's a compiled file. I don't know why they load it but they doesn't seem to use it anyway

Comment: @Andy it makes the creation of an email much faster, since, I can easily create repeatable components, since tables are quite a hassle to deal with. I also always forget how to use tables in HTML for some reason, so I'd rather just copy in paste what I do in this project into my future ones.